# I do not understand the template? can you help me?

Tags: c++

create a template function to exchange values ​​stored in the two variables that are passed to that function as arguments

Comment: This seems like homework. Ask your teacher.

Comment: Did you google "template function" and read about them?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a homework completion service. Your instructor gave you the assignment, not us, and you're going to need to do your own work. If we do it for you, you don't learn anything. If you can't get started, ask your teacher for help; they're being paid to teach you. Good luck.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The really smart answer is:

```
#include <algorithm>
```

As in:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

main() {
    int x = 1, y = 2;
    std::swap <int> (x, y);
    std::cout << "Expecting 2: " << x << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Expecting 1: " << y << std::endl;
}
```

Because `swap` is already included in `<algorithm>`!

The best C++ way is to use what's already in the library. Knowing what's there will help you write clean, minimal, and robust code.

If you have to roll your own, then just copy the code from [cplusplus](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/swap/) and change it up a bit, here I changed `c` to `t` and slid the `&`s over:

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
void swap (T &a, T &b) {
    T t(a);
    a = b;
    b = t;
}

main() {
    int x = 1, y = 2;
    swap <int> (x, y);
    std::cout << "Expecting 2: " << x << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Expecting 1: " << y << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: How does it benefit anyone if you do this poster's homework?

Comment: @KenWhite - http://threevirtues.com/

Comment: @YiminRong all 3 virtues are given in context to actually _writing_ the code.  The quote from Larry might be applicable if say, OP had written a program to parse webpages for answers to homework...

Comment: @YiminRong: The [site guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6166/42757)